# Disk space problem when migrating a VPS to another cloud infrastructure

Tags: iso, vps, cloud

I created an Ubuntu VPS on a cloud infrastructure and customized some configurations on it then exported it as an ISO image. I uploaded and 'attached' it to 2 other different cloud service providers and on both I can not perform operations as I get messages related to insufficient space on disk whereas the server itself is less than 4 GB and there is plenty of space on the disk on cloud I got which is 20 GB. 
Should I have done any particular operation (e.g. particular mounting operation) before attaching it on the new clouds ?

Comment: How did you export the original VPS image?  If the filesystem of the image is not the same size as the new VPS allocation, you can expand the image filesystem using `resize2fs` ... [resize2fs manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs)

Comment: I used **Systemback** (https://askubuntu.com/questions/534210/how-to-create-an-iso-from-current-installation) utility.

Comment: It's very likely that the file system size has the minimum size required to fit the files from your imaged server.  So, use of `resize2fs` seems appropriate here.

Comment: The system is on a cloud with only one disk. Will I be able to resize the file system within the same disk ?

Comment: You can resize the filesystem to the extents of the partition on the disk.  If the disk has multiple partitions, the filesystem can only reach to the extents of the partition in which the image has been restored... use `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT` to get information on partition sizes.